# React-Redux mapStateToProps Usage for Multiple States in a Single Container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Disclaimer: This is the first React/Redux project I am involved with. Just trying to fill in while the project owner is away on vacation by editing some existing code.

Currently the application manages a table of `data` that updates with API calls to another server. I want to add a separate state `id` that manages an identifier for the `data` that gets updated via a form so that the table data changes on the form button click.

I *believe* I am having trouble with the `mapStateToProps` function and would like a sanity check. I say *believe* because everything else looks correct in the application and it is more by process of elimination than an outright smoking gun that I think it is the `mapStateToProps` issue.

The original `mapStateToProps` is written as follows to manage a table of `data`.

```
function mapStateToProps({ data: { data, ...state } }) {
  const mappedDatas = data.map((data) => {
    return Object.assign({}, data, { data: new Array(data) });
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    datas: mappedDatas,
  };
}
```

My proposed change to adding an `id` for the `data` is as follows.

```
function mapStateToProps({ data: { data, ...state } }) {
  const mappedDatas = data.map((data) => {
    return Object.assign({}, data);
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    datas: mappedDatas,
    id: state.id,
  };
}
```

Thank you.

---

EDIT: adding components and reducers

#### Reducers

`data.js`

```
import * as TYPES from '../constants/actionTypes';

const data = {
  data: [],
  dataModalOpen: false,
};

export default function dataReducer(state = data, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.LOAD_DATAS_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { loading: true });

    case TYPES.LOAD_DATAS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { data: [...action.payload], loading: false });

    case TYPES.LOAD_DATAS_ERROR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { loading: false });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`id.js`

```
import * as TYPES from '../constants/actionTypes';

const id = {
  id: [],
  dataModalOpen: false,
};

export default function dataReducer(state = id, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.OPEN_DATA_MODAL:
      return Object.assign({}, state);

    case TYPES.CLOSE_DATA_MODAL:
      return Object.assign({}, state);

    case TYPES.FIND_ID_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { loading: true });

    case TYPES.FIND_ID_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { idData: [...state.id, { ...action.payload}] });

    case TYPES.FIND_ID_ERROR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { loading: false });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### Components

`DatasTable.jsx`

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';
import { Paper, Toolbar, ToolbarGroup, ToolbarTitle, Table, TableBody, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn, IconButton } from 'material-ui';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';
import Loader from './Loader';

type PropsType = {
  datas: Array<{
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
  }>,
  id: string,
  loading: boolean,
  onAdd: Function,
  onSelect: Function,
};

export default function({ datas, loading, onAdd, onSelect }: PropsType) {
  return (
    <Paper>
      <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarGroup>
          <ToolbarTitle text="Data" />
        </ToolbarGroup>

        <ToolbarGroup>
          <IconButton touch onClick={onAdd}>
            <ContentAdd />
          </IconButton>
        </ToolbarGroup>
      </Toolbar>

      <Loader loading={loading}>
        <Table onRowSelection={onSelect}>
          <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Foo</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Bar</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>

          <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false} showRowHover>
            {
              datas.map(({ foo, bar }) => (
                <TableRow key={foo}>
                  <TableRowColumn>{foo}</TableRowColumn>
                  <TableRowColumn>{bar}</TableRowColumn>
                </TableRow>
              ))
            }
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Loader>
    </Paper>
  )
}
```

`Form.jsx`

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';
import { Paper, TextField, RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';

type PropsType = {
  id: Array<{
    idData: string,
  }>,  
  onSubmit: Function,
  onChange: Function,
};

export default function({ id, onSubmit, onChange }: PropsType) {

  return (
    <Paper>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <TextField
          name="id"
          onChange={onChange}
          floatingLabelText="Identifier Key"
          value={id}
        />

        <RaisedButton
          label="Find"
          primary
          type="submit"
        />
      </form>
    </Paper>
  )
}
```

Comment: what is happening now and do you have errors/warnings/logs that you can post? Also what is the value of `state.id`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. `state.id` gets returned as `[object Object]`. There is no warning log and the state gets initiated properly as shown by the following. `Object
data
:
Object
data
:
Array[1]
dataModalOpen
:
false
loading
:
false
__proto__
:
Object
id
:
Object
dataModalOpen
:
false
id
:
Array[0]
loading
:
true
__proto__
:
Object
notifications
:
Array[0]
routing
:
Object
services
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: mapStateToProps is entirely wrong. It shouldn't just return state. It doesn't need to use Object.assign. Naming anything "data" is s terrible idea. Naming *multiple* things "data" is terribly confusing. `id` should probably not be a property on the date itself, but instead on some sub object in a list of more of the same kind of objects. Without more code (reducer, component) I can't say more.

Comment: Also mapStateToProps doesn't manage data. It picks data from the state to pass along to the component. It can sometimes format the data to suit the component. But the state is managed by the reducer(s). Note that the the original mapStateToProps that you are modifying is already entirely wrong. Instead of using `new Array(x)` just use `[x]` but there's no need or use for it here.

Comment: Thanks very much @DDS. I have added the components and reducers code.

Comment: Please rename everything named "data" to what it actually is so it isn't so terribly confusing. This is unfortunately so hard to follow that is very hard to say shunting useful about it without an in depth study which would probably start with naming things more appropriately. This is like decoding obfuscated code. Also `data` is the plural of `datum` so `datas` is not a word.